# How to display a message in the browser every second using PHP

Tags: php, iis

Has anyone found a solution, how to display a message in the browser every second using PHP?
Until now, I've always used the following code, which worked fine on my server running IIS 6:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
        echo "Message after " . $counter . " second(s)<br>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
      }
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen several posts that `ob_flush` no longer works with the newer IIS versions.
I use IIS on Windows 10.

In some posts I read to add `responseBufferLimit="0"` into the section `PHP_via_FastCGI` of the file `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`.

But in this file I've only the following section about `fastCgi` so I've no idea how to add `responseBufferLimit="0"` into this section:

```
  <fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\Program Files\PHP\php-cgi.exe" />
  </fastCgi>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the result that you are actually seeing? Are you starting an output buffer somewhere. I’m not going to argue with your code, you probably have your reasons, but I think JS with XHR or similar might be a more common and modern solution

Comment: can you not use the javascript?

Comment: Actually, I need this kind of code to send an email every few seconds and then display the email address in the browser. When I call this test code, nothing happens in the browser. Only the "hourglass" circles in the top left of Google Chrome's tab and after 10 seconds all 10 messages are displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some tests. It's still a workaround, but a bit smarter and I think as long as there's no better solution, you can live with it.
You just have to add `echo str_repeat(" ", 7500000);` at the very beginning of your code and `ob_flush()` and `flush()` will do what they're supposed to do (also with the new IIS versions):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      echo str_repeat(" ", 7500000);

      for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
        echo "Message after " . $counter . " second(s)<br>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
      }
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code is definitely not a smart and good solution, but maybe you can use it as a workaround until someone here shows us the smart solution, which I'm also very interested in.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
        echo "Message after " . $counter . " second(s)";
        echo str_repeat(" ", 10000000) . "<br>";
        sleep(1);
      }
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, this does exactly what I want to do. For sure it's not nice but as a workaround it's just great. Many thanks.

Comment: That's great. In the meantime I've implemented this workaround on all my websites and now the output looks exactly like it used to look on IIS 6 with ```ob_flush```. I'm aware that this is not the perfect solution. But it's a workaround that works great. If someone knows a smarter solution, I'll be happy to adapt it accordingly. But for now I'm very happy. Seeky, many thanks for this great workaround. PS: No idea who rated this solution as not useful. For me it's very useful.